# Column filter on button click in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Morning all,

New to datatables, python and jquery so bear with me. I'm trying to get a datatables table imported through python to filter on column results on a button click.  I've searched for answers to this already, but most seem to be geared around text filters or selector filters, which isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Here's a JSFiddle mockup I created:

https://jsfiddle.net/4m5up9bx/2/

```
    <div align=center><a href="a" class="navy small btn">Mapping Tools</a>
    <a href="b" class="teal small btn">Charting Tools</a>
    <a href="c" class="green small btn">Analyzing Data</a>
    <a href="d" class="yellow small btn">Programming Tools</a>
    <a href="e" class="orange small btn">Other Data Tools</a></div>


    <table id="tools" border=1 cellpadding=7>
        <thead>
        <th>Program</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Skill Level</th>
        <th>Website</th>


    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            {% for obj in object_list %}

            <td><a href="{{ obj.id }}/">{{ obj.program }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ obj.type }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.skill_level }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ obj.website }}/">{{ obj.website }}</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Doesn't quite work without the python but will give you the gist. To start, the table displays all results, as you might expect.  Essentially, all I want to do is allow for someone to click one of the buttons and have the table filter if the column "Type" equals a set text value.

I have a field ('Type') which includes five set values: Mapping, Charts, Data Analysis, Programming and Other.

So, if someone were to click the Mapping Tools button, I'd like the datatable to filter only to results where {{obj.type}} = "Mapping"  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use server-side datatable. where you can pass custom parameter for your object (ie, mapping, charts)to an ajax request and fetch json data and show on the datatable. or you can check "[Generated content for a column](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html)"